# sql plus warning in procedure. procedure created with compilation error. (procedure with parameter)

Tags: oracle

hey i am trying to do a pl sql program with the help of procedure. i want to check if number given by user is even or odd using procedure but i am getting an warning : procedure created with compilation error .

```
create or replace procedure even( a in out number)
as n number :=&n;
begin
if(n,2)=0 then
dbms_output.put_line('even');
else
dbms_output.put_line('odd');
end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Did you check the error message? It should tell you exactly WHERE the error is. In any case, what do you think `(n,2)` means? And did you mean an equal sign right after it, not a minus?

Comment: oh sry it is equal sign. and yes  i checked error message. it is saying  pls-00412 :list of values not allowed as argument to this function or procedure.

Comment: You are missing the keyword `mod` in the IF branch. It seems like you know you need to calculate a modulus, so missing the function name is a trivial syntax error which you should have been able to solve for yourself instead of posting a question here..

Answer (score 1):

It is meaningless to compile the procedure each time you get user input.You should rather be doing the following.

Compile the procedure without any substitution variables. The parameter  should be just `IN` and not `IN OUT` unless you want to modify its value inside the procedure.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Even(n IN NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
    IF MOD(n, 2) = 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('even');
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('odd');
    END IF;
END;

/
```

Then execute this compiled procedure as many times as you like by passing user input.

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL> EXEC even ( &n );
Enter value for n: 5
odd

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC even ( &n );
Enter value for n: 4
even

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thank you. I realised where I went wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sayali : There is a special way to say thanks in SO. Please do read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use you mod function:

```
if mod(a,2)=0 then
dbms_output.put_line('even');
else
dbms_output.put_line('odd');
end if;
```

I think you put "n" instead of "a"

Comment: sure you will have compilation error if you missed to write "mod"

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a **function** instead; in my opinion, it is a better option for such a task than a procedure.

A *natural* choice would be a function that returns Boolean:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_is_even (par_n in number)
  2    return boolean
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return mod(par_n, 2) = 0;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.
```

You'd then use it in some **PL/SQL** code as the following example (yes, it looks stupid because it appears that it does exactly what your procedure does, but note - this is *just an example*; in real life, you'd use it in smarter way):

```
SQL> begin
  2    if f_is_even(6) then
  3       dbms_output.put_Line('even');
  4    else
  5       dbms_output.put_Line('odd');
  6    end if;
  7  end;
  8  /
even

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Drawback of such a function is that you can't use it in SQL (but, as I said, PL/SQL):

```
SQL> select f_is_even(5) from dual;
select f_is_even(5) from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06553: PLS-382: expression is of wrong type
```

A possible "workaround" is to create a procedure that doesn't return Boolean but, for example, number (0 for "false" and 1 for "true") or string (N for "false, no" and Y for "true, yes"). For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_is_even_01 (par_n in number)
  2    -- returns 1 if number is even; returns 0 if number is odd
  3    return number
  4  is
  5  begin
  6    return case when mod(par_n, 2) = 0 then 1
  7                else 0
  8           end;
  9  end;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_is_even_01(5) r1,
  2         f_is_even_01(6) r2
  3  from dual;

        R1         R2
---------- ----------
         0          1
```

There's nothing *wrong* in using a procedure; I just thought that you might want to hear another opinion.